# How would I go about converting a string algorithm into actual code?

Tags: java, algorithm, theory

For example, say I had the string

`hunger > 80 then findFood();`

or

`distanceTo sun < 30 then moveAwayFrom(sun);`

That's not the exact syntax of what I want, but does anyone know a simple way I could make it so that I can pass that onto an entity in a game and they will basically follow that? The only thing that spring to mind at the moment is making a huge block of if statements that parse the given string, but that feels really really ineffecient.

I'd like a second opinion, just to see if I'm overlooking something really simple here :/

Comment: You could just write a simple [Recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

Comment: You could get funky with reflection, but please think of your own sanity.

Comment: Of course there is. Something like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) will parse language statements.

Comment: @BartoszKP I'll look into that, I have a curse where I can't learn anything from a Wiki page, it all just flies over me :L

Comment: lol, I really don't get why the close votes :|

Comment: Some people are obviously having a bad day, this is a decent question.

Comment: You can also embed some already-existing scripting language inside your Java game, Python or JavaScript are a good starting point.

Comment: The technical term for this is a "DSL", which stands for "Domain Specific Language". Java doesn't provide any special support for Embedded Domain Specific Languages (EDSLs), so this question basically amounts to "how do I write a parser?" (or, "how do I write an interpreter?"). This is one of the things that you would learn in a computer science course, and also you can just Google it.

Comment: Actually Lua is quite popular in game development, I guess because it's nice and simple and yet it's a full programming language.

Answer (score 3):

Not an easy task! What you are basically saying is that you need to create a language.

This language will describe all possible commands which you will then parse and generate commands from.

Now you might be thinking to yourself "gee, I've never written a language before!". That's where [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/) comes in. It allows you to write the grammar for your language, and then generate the parser/lexer that you will need to decode the commands. You can get an IDE for working with ANTLER called [ANTLRWorks](http://tunnelvisionlabs.com/products/demo/antlrworks), and you should check out the [getting started tutorial](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Getting+Started+with+ANTLR+v4). You really will have to get over your "curse" of trouble with wiki pages and dive in here.

Along the way you will probably realize easier or more efficient ways to encode your commands so that you can later decode them. Some possible alternatives are embedding a scripting language which you will use to encode/decode the commands, such as Python, JavaScript, or Lua. I have seen Lua used in games before, you can read their statement on why they are popular in games [here](https://sites.google.com/site/marbux/home/where-lua-is-used#Dj8w97RHixgjHdycMbhinw). Good luck!